# HDMI audio not detected after update from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, hdmi

After updating my system I had all my hdmi outputs grayed out in audio settings. I reinstalled `alsa-base` and hdmi outputs entirely gone. Also I tried to reinstall video driver, installed one from intel. I edited `/etc/default/grub` and added there `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.preliminary_hw_support=1` with no effect. What else should I check to make it work again?

```
 lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT 
Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [1458:d000]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: i915


aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC269VC Digital [ALC269VC Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Haswell should just work.

Comment: I read that. But it does not.